# How do you logout of Facebook Mobile?

Tags: facebook, mobile

I'm visiting www.facebook.com on the web browser on a Samsung Galaxy Tab, Android version 2.2, and I can't find any way to log out of Facebook once I'm logged in.

I want to emphasize that I'm not using a native app, but instead viewing Facebook in a mobile browser, in this case the native webkit browser.

Edit: I don't appear to have a "More" button to click on to log out. Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to logout of there from a desktop browser.

1. Login to Facebook
2. Go to Account -> Account Settings
3. In the **Settings** tab (the first one), go to **Account Security**
4. Click on **change**[image]
5. Go to **Account Activity** -> **Most Recent Activity**[image]
6. You should see the session from your phone.
7. Click on **end activity**

From here: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211990645501187

Answer (score 0):

Use the **More** drop-down menu on the right of the navigation bar at the top. It has the **Log Out** option towards the end.

Comment: I don't appear to have that button, see updated screenshot. =(

Comment: @Raul can you also add the URL that you are looking at then

Comment: I enter "http://www.facebook.com", which gets redirected to "http://m.facebook.com".

Comment: This is bizarre. Which version of Android are you running? Stock standard browser as I understand, yes?

Comment: @Dmitry Android 2.2, using stock standard browser.

Comment: @Raul Very strange, I'm at a loss here..

Comment: @Raul: Do you have a hardware "menu" button?